# promise chaining when splitting the chain

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

In the following code

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('a');
    resolve();
});

p.then(() => {    
    console.log('b');

}).then(() => {    
    console.log('c');    
});

p.then(() => {
    console.log('z');
})
```

I expect the console output to be:
a
b
c
z

Instead I got:
a
b
z
c

but with this code I got the expected result

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('a');
    resolve();
}).then(() => {    
    console.log('b');
}).then(() => {    
    console.log('c');    
});

p.then(() => {
    console.log('z');
})
```

Can anyone explain the way promise chaining is done in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `then` returns you new `Promise` which depends of callback resolution.

That's difference.

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('a');
    resolve();
});

var a = p.then(() => {    
    console.log('b');

});
a.then(() => {    
    console.log('c');    
});

p.then(() => {
    console.log('z');
});
```

Timeline:

- initial resolve // a
- p resolved // b, z  independently
- a resolved // c

In second case your `p` points to promise returned by last `then`:

```
var a = new Promise(foo('a'));
var b = a.then(foo('b'));
var p = b.then(foo('c'));
p.then(foo('z'));
```

*You should not to rely on one level resolving order. Because this happens eventually and order is realy undefined(depend on internal implementation).*